# How to increase the font size of FCM push notification text

Tags: android, html, push-notification, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

How to increase the font size or change the font of FCM push notification body.

```
 let FCMmessage = {
  to: '/topics/marketing',
  data: data,
  'priority': 'high',
  notification: {
    image: 'url-to-image',
    body:'body'
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating a custom layout with different font sizes and using Notification#setContent(RemoteViews r)?

Comment: Since I am a fresher I don't know how to use it. can you please explain how to use it